# Decimal part is lost when returned from function

Tags: c

I have a problem when passing the decimal number from function - take a look at the code.

This function where I am searching for number in arguments of function main on position 2 works just fine, but if I call the function it doesn't return the decimal part. For example input is 15.25 - function take 15.25, but when that value is returned to a variable it shows 15.00. Do you have any ideas why?

BTW: I made that function much simpler for this example.

```
int arg_find(char *argv[]) { 
    double result;
    int i = 0;
    double dec = 1;
    while ((argv[2][i] >= '0' && argv[2][i] <= '9') || argv[2][i] == '.') {
        // lets say in argv[2] is 14.25
        if (argv[2][i] == '.') {
            decimal = true;
            i++;
        }
        if (decimal == true) {
            dec *= 10;
            result += (argv[2][i] - '0')/dec;            
            i++;
        } else {
            result = result * 10 + (argv[2][i] - '0');
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I call the function

```
double result2;
result2 = arg_find(argv); //in result2 is 14
```

Comment: `arg_find` returns an integer, not a floating point number.

Comment: Really, what did you expect? That a datatype called `int` will hold a non-integer? Just use your common sense. Do use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very simple and obvious because your function `arg_find` returns an integer not a float hence you are facing the problem.

You may try to define it as:

```
double arg_find(char *argv[])
```

instead of

```
int arg_find(char *argv[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your function as

```
double arg_find(char *argv[])
```

Comment: Oh, my I changed everything literally.. This is awesome I have forgotten that the function is pasing int. For god sake - thank you so much :)